# How to handle empty array in http response with retrofit in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am new to kotlin and observers. I'm using Retrofit to do API calls. My API calls return the response as an empty array. I could not figure it out how to handle it with the use of observers. Please, anyone, help me out. Thanks in advance

API call method :

```
@GET("transaction/get")
fun getTransactions(@Query("date") date: String?, @Query("user_id") user_id: Int, @Query("account_id") account_id: Int?): Observable<TransactionModel>
```

Connection class

```
public class ApiServiceNetwork private constructor()//hide the public constructor
    : Interceptor {
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        val builder: Request.Builder
        builder = request.newBuilder()
        val request1 = builder.build()
        //Here we can modify request1 and response if we want (like adding header or auth)
        val response = chain.proceed(request1)

        return response
    }

    private val logger: okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor
        get() {
            val logging = okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            logging.level = okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS
            logging.level = okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC
            logging.level = okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            return logging
        }

    fun getNetworkService(): WebServiceInterface {
        return createRetrofitInstance(EndPoint.SERVER_ENDPOINT).create(WebServiceInterface::class.java)
    }

    private fun createRetrofitInstance(url: String): Retrofit {
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        okHttpClient.addInterceptor(this)
        okHttpClient.addNetworkInterceptor(StethoInterceptor())
        okHttpClient.addInterceptor(logger)
        retrofit.baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().setLenient().create()))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient.connectTimeout(60,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(60,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(60,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS).build())
        return retrofit.build()

    }

    companion object {
        private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()

        fun getInstance(): ApiServiceNetwork {
            return ApiServiceNetwork()
        }
    }
```

Function call in my activity :

```
mApiServiceNetwork.getNetworkService().getTransactions(date, user_id, account_id)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({

                    this.transaction = it

                    this.expenseDataAdapter.setExpenses(it.expenses!!)
                    this.recyclerView.adapter = expenseDataAdapter

                    this.textViewSpendingAccount.text = it.account!!.title

                    this.textViewSpendingExpense.text = it.total_expense.toString()
                    this.textViewSpendingIncome.text = it.total_income.toString()
                    this.textViewSpendingBalance.text = it.balance.toString()

                    Log.d("__EXPENSE", it.total_expense.toString())

                }, {
                    Toast.makeText(this.requireContext(), it.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }, {
                    this.expenseDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                })
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you NEVER care about the data in the response (i.e. if it's always an empty array) you can use `Completable` instead of `Observable<TransactionModel>`. Looking at your code this doesn't seem like the case.
2. If the response sometimes has data and sometimes returns an empty array you can use a custom `Converter.Factory` to intercept calls before the GSON converter factory and format the return the way you want. This limits the empty responses to calls that you can accept.

An example with pseudo code:

```
class EmptyArrayConverterFactory : Converter.Factory() {

    override fun responseBodyConverter(type: Type, annotations: Array<Annotation>, retrofit: Retrofit): Converter<ResponseBody, *>? {
        val delegate = retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter<Any>(this, type, annotations)
        return Converter<ResponseBody, Any> { body ->
            var bodyString = body.String()
            if (bodyString == "{[]}") { // Or whatever the empty array is returned as
                bodyString = //Convert body string to empty/error TransactionModel JSON
            }
            delegate.convert(bodyString) 
        }
    }

}
```

3. Another option if the response sometimes has data and sometimes does not you can return an `Observable<ResponseBody>` instead of `Observable<TransactionModel>` and then parse the response yourself in the `subscribe()` function, taking into account the possibility of an empty array. I think this would be the most flexible option given the circumstances and my limited knowledge of your situation.

This would look something like this:

API definition:
    @GET("transaction/get")
    fun getTransactions(@Query("date") date: String?, @Query("user_id") user_id: Int, @Query("account_id") account_id: Int?): Observable

Usage:

```
mApiServiceNetwork.getNetworkService().getTransactions(date, user_id, account_id)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ responseBody ->

                if(responseBody.string() == "{[]}"){
                    // handle the empty list however you want
                }
                else{ 
                    // Handle the response normally
                    this.transaction = it

                    this.expenseDataAdapter.setExpenses(it.expenses!!)
                    this.recyclerView.adapter = expenseDataAdapter

                    this.textViewSpendingAccount.text = it.account!!.title

                    this.textViewSpendingExpense.text = it.total_expense.toString()
                    this.textViewSpendingIncome.text = it.total_income.toString()
                    this.textViewSpendingBalance.text = it.balance.toString()

                    Log.d("__EXPENSE", it.total_expense.toString())
                }

            }, {
                Toast.makeText(this.requireContext(), it.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }, {
                this.expenseDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 2nd one is my case. Can u please give me more details about how to use Observable<ResponseBody> in this scenario

Comment: Added a code example for option 3 which uses the ResponseBody